# Develop Chrome extension that connects to redux store in web page

Tags: redux, google-chrome-extension, redux-devtools

I am trying to develop a simple chrome extension that connects to an existing redux store running in a page in a tab.

I have a helloworld chrome extension running with a v3 manifest.

My html for my popup looks like :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="monitor.css">
    <script src="chrome-extension://lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/js/redux-devtools-extension.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class='container' >
            <div>
                <label>Redux Dev Tools</label>
                <button id='connect' >Connect</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id='action'>
                    <option id=1>SIGNED_IN</option>
                    <option id=1>SIGNED_OUT</option>
                    <option id=1>FETCH_ALL_BRAND_LINES</option>
                </select>
                <button id='sendAction' >Dispatch</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='logWindow' id='log'>Log</div>
        </div>
        <script src="monitor.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem comes from trying to load the js from the redux-devtools plugin.

> Refused to load the script
> 'chrome-extension://lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/js/redux-devtools-extension.js'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'self'"

My manifest file content-security is configured as follows :

```
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    },
```

But I am really struggling to understand what I need to do to allow this script to be loaded.

Can anyone suggest what I should try?

Comment: Did you happen to figure out how to connect to the redux store running on the page? I'm trying to do that myself and not sure how to go about it.